# Windows Firewall Remote IP Address Scope List Limit

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I had read in the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/712831/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-ip-addresses-for-a-windows-firewall-rules-sco) that the Remote IP Address scope list limit is 1000 in Windows Firewall for a given rule.  I am however at 1043 entries in the remote IP Address scope list and still able to add more (both programmatically and interactively through the GUI) without issue.  The question/answer specifically referenced Windows Server 2008R2 so I checked the behavior under that OS and it seems like the 1000 limit is not a problem there either.

Is the answer wrong or was there some sort of patch released since that question was asked/answered which upped the limit?  I have looked on the internet to see if there is an upper limit to the scope list and have been unable to find any documentation other than the previously mentioned post.

Is there a realistic limit and what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Microsoft software engineer who worked on Windows Firewall [provided an answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/32614b57-f3a3-437f-a659-4777f5e6bd68/windows-firewall-limits) to essentially the same question:

> Is anybody aware about Windows 2008 firewall limits like Max Number of
>   Rules or Max Number of Remote Addresses?

And his answer:

> There is no limit to how many rules can be added(other than the cap of
>   UINT64 for the filterId), nor how many conditions can be in each
>   filter (other than the cap of a UINT32 for the numFilterConditions).

Comment: In practice, a rule can have 1000 entries in the scope. See https://superuser.com/questions/712831/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-ip-addresses-for-a-windows-firewall-rules-sco

Comment: I am curious as to the cause -- is that possible 1000 rule cap like the UINT(*) caps listed here? And if not what else could be causing it 'in practice' for the person mentioning something like that in the other answer? And is it different for 32/64 architectures?

Comment: I've run into this issue on every 64 bit Windows I've tested on (8, 10 and Server 2012). Have not tried 32 bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For Anything older than Windows 11 / Server 2022, limit is 1000. Limit for Windows 11 and Server 2022 is now 10000. Found limits through trial and error.

Beware adding more than 10k conditions per type to the lower level windows filtering platform api on Windows 11 - you can get blue screens. Now I know why the windows firewall limit is 10000 and not higher on that operating system.